# How to create an advanced filter search?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, customization, search

This is not really much of a technical question but it is more like an intro to the topic I want to talk about.

So this is my first time creating an advanced search custom page in which I need to get post according to the custom post type, custom taxonomies, years and the order by.

The problem is that I really have not idea in how to star here. I've been looking for tutorials or snippets in the Internet but everything I find somehow can not work with dropdowns(why?, i don't know), all the tutorials that I have found are about using check-boxes.

So any recommendation or function code you guys can tell me about?.

Thanks in advance.

This is the HTML code I want to use:

```
<!-- Post Type -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_type">Post Type</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>Any</option>
            <option>Post</option>
            <option>Portfolio</option>
            <option>Snippet</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Taxonomy -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_type">Taxonomy</label>
        <select class="form-control" multiple>
            <option>Any</option>
            <option>category</option>
            <option>portfolio_categories</option>
            <option>snippets_categories</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Year -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_type">Year</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>Any</option>
            <option>2018</option>
            <option>2017</option>
            <option>2016</option>
            <option>2015</option>
            <option>2014</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Orderby -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_type">Order by</label>
        <select class="form-control" multiple>
            <option>Any</option>
            <option>Author</option>
            <option>Popularity (# of Comments)</option>
            <option>Views post_views_count</option>
            <option>Year</option>
            <option>ASC</option>
            <option>DESC</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Search Button -->
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="buscar_btn" value="Search">
    <noscript>&lt;b&gt;Your browser does not support Javascript, this making it unable to display the posts.&lt;/b&gt;</noscript>
    <div id="resultados"><div class="cargando_medio"></div></div>
</div>
```

Here is the function for the post_view_count custom field:

```
// Function to display number of views.
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 Views";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}

// Function to count views.
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}


// Add it to a column in WP-Admin
function posts_column_views($defaults){
    $defaults['post_views'] = __('Views');
    return $defaults;
}
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_column_views');
function posts_custom_column_views($column_name, $id){
    if($column_name === 'post_views'){
        echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
    }
}
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_column_views',5,2);
```

The function is not really good, actually is not good but it does the work. I may have to change it later on, especially because I want it to count views per IP address and per day; it currently does it by counting the views per every REFRESH I do in the current page/post.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a `function` that will search posts based on the selected options? Can you post the code for the advanced search `form`?

Comment: Yes ,see my updated question. I'm trying to use Ajax so there's not really a form. I just need the function and from there I can create the Ajax calls that I need to make it work.

Comment: I see. But are the Taxonomy options just placeholders? I mean, you don't have a taxonomy named "1", "2", etc., do you? And same to the other `select` menus; I suppose you'd use the correct `value` later on?

Comment: Yes, do you need the years and the order by info as well? ... I mean there's not really anything I have customized in there. If I'm not mistaken theres a function in WordPress that I can use to foreach the years and the orderby select.. I will look into that after I'm done with the post type ans taxonomies.

Comment: I actually have the `function` for querying the posts based on the options you defined (e.g. post type and taxonomy); however, it doesn't include the part which sorts the results by "Views". Do your posts have a custom field for the "View" part?

Comment: Oh my God, you're actually doing it (somehow I took your last comment as sarcasm...don't know why, sorry) thank you. Yes, I do have custom field for that and its respective function as well. I will update my answer... Thank you!.

Comment: I've posted an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**PHP**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_adv_search', 'ajax_my_adv_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_adv_search', 'ajax_my_adv_search' );
function ajax_my_adv_search() {
    if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'my-adv-search', 'q_nonce', false ) ) {
        echo 'session_expired';
        wp_die();
    }

    $post_type = isset( $_POST['q_post_type'] ) ? $_POST['q_post_type'] : '';
    $taxonomy = isset( $_POST['q_taxonomy'] ) ? $_POST['q_taxonomy'] : [];
    $year = isset( $_POST['q_year'] ) ? $_POST['q_year'] : '';
    $orderby = isset( $_POST['q_orderby'] ) ? $_POST['q_orderby'] : [];
    $order = isset( $_POST['q_order'] ) ? $_POST['q_order'] : '';

    // Note that if $post_type is 'any', all post statuses will be included. In
    // that case, you may want to set specific post statuses below.
    $post_status = '';

    $taxonomy = array_filter( (array) $taxonomy );
    if ( ! in_array( 'any', $taxonomy ) ) {
        $taxonomy = array_unique( array_map( 'trim', $taxonomy ) );

        add_filter( 'posts_join', function( $c ) use ( $taxonomy ) {
            if ( ! empty( $taxonomy ) ) {
                global $wpdb;
                // 1 below is one/number and not the lowercase of L
                $c .= " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS ctr1 ON ctr1.object_id = {$wpdb->posts}.ID" .
                    " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS ctt1 ON ctt1.term_taxonomy_id = ctr1.term_taxonomy_id";
            }
            return $c;
        } );

        add_filter( 'posts_where', function( $c ) use ( $taxonomy ) {
            if ( ! empty( $taxonomy ) ) {
                $tax_list = array_map( 'esc_sql', $taxonomy );
                $tax_list = "'" . implode( "', '", $tax_list ) . "'";

                // 1 below is one/number and not the lowercase of L
                $c .= " AND ( ctt1.taxonomy IN ($tax_list) )";
            }
            return $c;
        } );
    }

    if ( ! is_numeric( $year ) ) {
        $year = '';
    }

    $orderby = array_filter( (array) $orderby );
    if ( in_array( 'any', $orderby ) ) {
        // Don't sort by post date.
        $orderby2 = false;
    } else {
        $orderby = array_unique( array_map( 'trim', $orderby ) );

        // TRUE if we're sorting by year.
        $ob_year = false;

        foreach ( $orderby as $i => $s ) {
            // Sort posts by year.
            if ( 'year' === $s ) {
                $ob_year = true;
                unset( $orderby[ $i ] );
            }

            // Sort posts by views count. Note that this would only return
            // posts that have the custom field 'post_views_count'.
            if ( 'views_count' === $s ) {
                $meta_key = 'post_views_count';
                $orderby2 = 'meta_value_num';
                unset( $orderby[ $i ] );
            }
        }

        add_filter( 'posts_orderby', function( $c, $q ) use ( $ob_year ) {
            if ( $ob_year ) {
                global $wpdb;

                // Use the value parsed by WP_Query.
                $order = $q->get( 'order' );

                $c .= $c ? ', ' : '';
                $c .= "YEAR({$wpdb->posts}.post_date) $order";
            }
            return $c;
        }, 10, 2 );

        $ok = isset( $orderby2 );
        if ( ! $ok && empty( $orderby ) ) {
            // Don't sort by post date.
            $orderby2 = false;
        } elseif ( ! $ok ) {
            // Pass to WP_Query as a string.
            $orderby2 = implode( ' ', $orderby );
        }
    }

    $q = new WP_Query( [
        'post_status' => $post_status,
        'post_type'   => $post_type,
        'year'        => $year,
        'meta_key'    => isset( $meta_key ) ? $meta_key : '',
        'orderby'     => $orderby2,
        'order'       => $order,
    ] );

    if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
            $q->the_post();

            echo '<li>';
                the_title(); echo '; ID: '; the_ID();
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>No posts found.</p>';
    }

    wp_die();
}
```

**HTML**

Take a look at the "form" below, and make sure to set the proper ID in the corresponding `select` element/menu. You also need to add the 'order' fields in the "Order by" column, and *nonce* field before the submit/search button.

```
<div id="my-adv-search">
<!-- Post Type -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="q_post_type">Post Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="q_post_type">
            <option value="any" selected>Any</option>
            ...
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Taxonomy -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="q_taxonomy">Taxonomy</label>
        <select class="form-control" multiple id="q_taxonomy">
            <option value="any" selected>Any</option>
            ...
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Year -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="q_year">Year</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="q_year">
            <option value="any" selected>Any</option>
            ...
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Orderby -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="q_orderby">Order by</label>
        <select class="form-control" multiple id="q_orderby">
            <option value="any" selected>Any</option>
            <?php
            foreach ( [
              'author'        => 'Author',
              'comment_count' => 'Popularity (# of Comments)',
              'year'          => 'Year',
              'views_count'   => 'Views',
            ] as $value => $label ) {
              printf( '<option value="%s">%s</option>',
                esc_attr( $value ), esc_html( $label ) );
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="order" id="q_order-asc" value="ASC" />
      ASC
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="order" id="q_order-desc" value="DESC" checked />
      DESC
    </label>
</div>

<!-- Nonce field. -->
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'my-adv-search', 'q_nonce' ); ?>

<!-- Search Button -->
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="buscar_btn" value="Search">
    <noscript>&lt;b&gt;Your browser does not support Javascript, this making it unable to display the posts.&lt;/b&gt;</noscript>
    <div id="resultados"><div class="cargando_medio"></div></div>
</div>
</div><!-- End #my-adv-search -->
```

**JS/jQuery/AJAX**

See below for a sample JS/jQuery script which does the AJAX search.

```
jQuery( function( $ ){
    var ajaxurl = '/path/to/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

    function searchPosts( btn ) {
        var _btn_text = btn.value,
            q_order;

        btn.disabled = true;
        btn.value = 'Searching..';

        q_order = $( '#q_order-asc' ).is( ':checked' ) ?
            'ASC' : 'DESC';

        return $.post( ajaxurl, {
            action: 'my_adv_search',
            q_nonce: $( '#q_nonce' ).val(),
            q_post_type: $( '#q_post_type' ).val(),
            q_taxonomy: $( '#q_taxonomy' ).val(),
            q_year: $( '#q_year' ).val(),
            q_orderby: $( '#q_orderby' ).val(),
            q_order: q_order,
        } ).done( function( s ){
            if ( 'session_expired' === s ) {
                location.reload();
                return;
            }

            $( '#resultados' ).html( s );
        } ).always( function(){
            btn.value = _btn_text;
            btn.disabled = false;
        } );
    }

    $( '#buscar_btn', '#my-adv-search' ).on( 'click', function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();

        // Run AJAX search.
        searchPosts( this );

        // Remove button focus.
        this.blur();
    } );
} );
```

**Notes**

- In the `ajax_my_adv_search()` PHP function, I didn't use `tax_query` with the `WP_Query` call because we are querying for posts that are in one of the specified taxonomy keys (e.g. `category` for standard Post category, and `post_tags` for standard Post tags), and not in a *term* inside a taxonomy. Therefore, I used the `posts_join` and `posts_where` hooks in `WP_Query` to get the proper results for such kind of query.
- In the `ajax_my_adv_search()` PHP function, I also used the `posts_orderby` hook in `WP_Query` because *sorting* posts/results by year is by default not available in the `WP_Query` class.

Comment: I'm sure it would help readers, if you explained why filtering joins and order of WP_Query is needed here, instead of e.g. using tax_query and ordering array parameters.  
ps: avoid possible SQL injections and include the relevant code, just in case that link changes or it's content is removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @birgire. I completely forgot to escape the `$taxonomy` values.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Sort by post date, will that not also implicilty give a sort by year?

Comment: Yes, but technically sorting by date is (assuming the table prefix is *wp_*) `ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date`, while sorting by year is `ORDER BY YEAR( wp_posts.post_date )`, right? So I thought the OP wanted the second option. Correct me if I'm wrong, though.

Comment: What I had in mind was that the post date is already of the form `yyyy-mm-dd HH:ii:ss` and gives us the "natural" year order, by ordering by the date column. Another question arises is how will the order be for `ORDER BY YEAR( wp_posts.post_date )`, when all the posts have the same year. Just thinking of way to simplify and avoid extra manual SQL filter if possible ;-)

Comment: See this [image](https://i.imgur.com/IxTnSGk.jpg). But anyway, I'll let the OP decides whether he wants (or meant) to sort the posts by the full post date or just the year. If he chooses (or actually wanted) the first option, then I'll edit the code.